# Pass data to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am new to Laravel I just want to pass variable to view but every time I have got    `Undefined variable: companies`  error 
this is my Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $companies = Company::all();

    return view(
        'companies.index', [
             'companies' => $companies
        ]);
}
```

and this is my view:

```
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($companies as $company)
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ $company->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
```

I use Laravel version 5.5

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Where are you getting this error, in the view or in the controller?

Comment: In the View here is my view address: resources\views\companies\index.blade.php

Comment: Change `Company::all()` to `Company::get()`.

Comment: Write `dd($companies);` before returning the view in the Controller, to check if the variable is printed.

Comment: @StephenLake nothing change

Comment: still get that error nothing is printed @Laerte

Comment: try: `return view('companies.index')->with('companies', $companies);`

Comment: So, you are not calling the view from this method. You are calling it from another method or another controller.

Comment: The code is/was fine, except I'm not sure about that `all()`, as far as I know that is only applicable to hydrated collections so there has to be something you're not sharing with us, somewhere you're not calling the correct code. @Laerte is right. Something is off.

Comment: @Laerte  this is my view address resources\views\companies\index.blade.php you mean I call the wrong path?

Comment: @Mehran can you post your route definition?

Comment: I mean that you are not calling this `index()` function. Maybe the route is wrong or you are using a wrong url action, ir something like this. Try to review the path from the button/link to the function to find where it is going.

Comment: @Laerte ,@Stephen Lake Thanks that was my mistake,  I add the wrong route in web.php

Comment: @adam found a problem in web.php thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your route file on `routes/web.php` you have a route to the index function like so:

```
Route::get('urlToYourView', 'YourController@index');
```